# raid 1 & ml350 gen8 server with centos 6.2

Tags: centos, raid, hp

I have a proliant ml350p gen8 HP SERVER with centos 6.2 and two hard disk with 1 TB for both.

I have several GB of files and software about 100) with their configurations but I want to install RAID 1 (mirror).

Then:

1) I know that RAID configuration must be done in the starting phase because it is a delicate operation. But, now? Is it possibile to loose all the OS?

2) I don't find a clear tutorial for this RAID configuration. What about?

3) If (1) is true, how can I make a cloned OS backup? Is it possible?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes it's possible to lose what's on the disks already but generally people don't change RAID levels mid-production.
2) Press F5 during disk controller boot to load ACU and create a R1 Mirror - that's all - should say '1 Logical Disk' at controller boot.
3) Just DD it off somewhere or reinstall.